# JS, Use HTML instead of variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a "show more" button thats works. The problem I'm having is, it uses the text from `var text` I want it to use it directly from HTML, any suggestions?

```js
var status = "less";

function toggleText() {
  var text = "TEST";

  if (status == "less") {
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See Less";
    status = "more";
  } else if (status == "more") {
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See More";
    status = "less"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="textArea">
  <!-- Here I want to implement HTML code and show it when clicked "See More"-->
</div>

<a id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">See More</a>
```

Comment: `<Script>` should be `<script>`

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Tag names are case insensitive.

Comment: I just mentioned for best practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply change the `display` CSS-property of the element in question

```js
var status = "less";

function toggleText()
{
    
    if (status == "less") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See Less";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See More";
        status = "less"
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="textArea" style="display: none;">
    Here I want to implement HTML code and show it when clicked "See More"
</div>


<a id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">See More</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add a class to the container of both elements to change both of their statuses together.

Here, I add the class `less-mode` to the container to both show the text inside the `textArea` and change the button to `show less` instead of `show more`.

Instead of saving the state in the javascript, we can know the state by checking if the class already exists on the container.

There are two "modes":

- when `container` has the class `less-mode`, make `textArea` `display: block` to show it, and show the `less` element inside the link.
- when `container` doesn't have the class `less-mode`, make `textArea` `display: none` to hide it completely, and show the `more` element inside the link.

This way, most of the responsibility for the visual change lay in the **CSS** and **HTML**. the **JavaScript** code only switches between them

```js
const containerElement = document.getElementById("container");

function toggleText() {

  if (containerElement.classList.contains('less-mode')) {
    containerElement.classList.remove('less-mode');
  } else {
    containerElement.classList.add('less-mode');
  }
}
```

```css
.more-btn .less {
  display: none;
}

.more-btn .more {
  display: block;
}

#textArea {
  display: none;
}

.container.less-mode #textArea {
  display: block;
}

.container.less-mode .more-btn .less {
  display: block;
}

.container.less-mode .more-btn .more {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <a id="toggleButton" class="more-btn" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <div class="more">See More</div>
    <div class="less">See Less</div>
  </a>
  <div id="textArea">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="red">red text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to keep it as simple as possible.
The text is hidden by default, and once the button is clicked the text are style `display` attribute is been toggled from `none` to `block`.

```js
(function() {


  var text = document.getElementById('text');

  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var status = this.dataset.status;
    if (status === 'less') {
      this.dataset.status = 'more';
      this.innerHTML = 'See More';
      text.style.display = 'none'

    } else {
      this.dataset.status = 'less';
      this.innerHTML = 'See Less';
      text.style.display = 'block'

    }
  });

})();
```

```css
#text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium amet consectetur corporis cum cumque distinctio eveniet excepturi expedita facilis incidunt iure maxime nesciunt nulla numquam perferendis qui quo, sint velit?
</div>
<button id="button" data-status="less">See More</button>
```